# Transfering RAM from a dead Dell to a similar, working HP. Do the specs match?

Tags: memory, motherboard, dell-inspiron

Note: I already have RAM on the MP. But its like 0.99 of a GB and I want to add the 896MB ram from the Dell to improve it a bit and hopefully get Windows 8 installed.

My [Dell Inspiron 531s](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-531s/drivers) won’t start up. I assume it’s a faulty power supply for which I cannot afford a replacement. So I was hoping to double up on an equally crappy [HP Compaq dc5100M](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=454811&docId=emr_na-c00298170&docLocale=en_US). I wanted to transfer the two DDR2 RAM sticks from the Dell Inspiron 531s to the HP Compaq dc5100M. Now the problem is I’m not 100% sure that the RAM is compatible.

I checked the [HP model’s hardware reference PDF](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=454811&docId=emr_na-c00298170&docLocale=en_US) and page 14 has the RAM requirements. But since the Inspiron crashed, I have no way of knowing it’s RAM specifications and therefore cannot ensure its compatibility. I did however, [look at Dell’s official accessory store for DDR2 RAM](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/accessories/productdetails/a6993732) that is compatible with the 531s.

I thought if the specs for that store RAM stick are the ones needed to make it work with the 531s, then the original RAM I have already have in the Dell Inspiron 531s must equal those specifications. Meaning I can compare the accessory store RAM to the RAM needed for the HP.

I know I may sound like I’m explaining too much but I’ve really researched and nothing has seemed to help much. I just want a clear answer to this and I’d really appreciate one.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if it fits it should be compatible.

Mix-matched chips of different performance ratings will have speed settings gracefully degrade until finding a common operating mode. When doubling RAM from 1 GiB this is probably a worthwhile penalty.

It may not be compatible at all though. Usually, this is due to a chipset limitation regarding the storage size of a stick, or an incompatibility with a manufacturer's make or model. Often these issues can be overcome by updating the BIOS to a more recent verion (look for applicable changes in version notes/highlights).

One case where I wouldn't feel comfortable mixing is when the voltages are different. Anecdotally  speaking, low-voltage DIMMs generally run fine at higher voltages, but running undervolted can be unreliable if they even work.

You should look at the sticks for their labeling. Pay attention for things like PC2 and anything that looks like a voltage, searching for, or asking about their meaning when you find them.